# Tracking links contained in Ampscript variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Given following code:

```
SET @link1 = "http://www.salesforce.com/"
SET @linkvar = "This is <a href='%%=RedirectTo(@link1)=%%'>Link number one</a> and this is <a href='http://www.salesforce.com/'>Link number two</a>"
Output(TreatAsContent(CONCAT(@linkvar, ' - does this work?')))
```

Neither of these two links are tracked. Knowing that this resembles the [official method](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314602&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) of *avoiding* links from being tracked, is there any proven solution for allowing AmpScript variables contain substantial snippets of HTML with links? I see this as a viable use case in some solutions.

I have attempted a number of different variants of the above approach - neither of them seem to work. The snippet will always be received in full, and can hold an arbitrary number of links.

Comment: This might be me being completely stupid but i would switch ' and " in your example. It would be this then: `SET @link1 = 'http://www.salesforce.com/'
SET @linkvar = 'This is <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link1)=%%">Link number one</a> and this is <a href="http://www.salesforce.com/">Link number two</a>'
Output(TreatAsContent(CONCAT(@linkvar, ' - does this work?')))` I do believe href with ' is not valid html

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick - changing the quotes does unfortunately not haver any effect