# Tracking clicks when HTML passed in through ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working with a team that is trying to move from a custom system for generating emails to utilize SFMC. They have emails that they do the translations for and generate the HTML that they then send through a triggered send. On the SFMC end all we have is

`%%Body%%`

And they then send the HTML in a body variable in the triggered send. The issue is that any links included in the HTML sent in the body variable are not being tracked. Everything works and renders fine, except the tracking, is there something I can do to get this tracking to function correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using SFMC like this.  You're missing a ton of opportunities for personalization and reporting by sending the email HTML over in one big blob.  If you can, just send raw data in your payload and let the HTML live in SMFC.

To answer your question, in order for the contents to be processed you'll need to output it like this:

```
%%[

set @body = AttributeValue("body")

if empty(@body) then
  raiseError("message body is empty",1)
endif

set @body = Replace(@body,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http')
set @body = Replace(@body,"href='http","href='httpgetwrap|http")

]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(@body)=%%
```

**Reference:**

- [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [TreatAsContent](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontent/)
- [HttpGetWrap](https://ampscript.guide/httpgetwrap/)

Comment: Will this not just parse ampscript in the payload (if any)? Per my experience, this will not force MC to apply tracking to links in html printed in an ampscript var. This was also my own question few years ago: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302422/tracking-links-contained-in-ampscript-variable

Comment: You're right.  In order to get this to work, you'll need to prefix all of the URLs with `httpgetwrap|`.  Updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: The `httpgetwrap` only works on a certain number of unique links per send job, IIRC.

Comment: Indeed, but then it also has a finite number of links it can track per job.  If these are personalised (eg preference center) this counts as a unique link for each contact. So yes, in many cases this will work. But far from a perfect solution.

Comment: Reason #142 to not use SFMC like a dumb sending engine.